# Python RegEx not working - Django

Tags: python, regex, django

[image]I am trying to match the text: `details/1234/`

using a regex: `r'^details/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$'`

Where article_id is passed to the expression as a parameter. This is not returning any matches on Pythex and (obviously) Django.

I also tried:

`r'^details/(?P<details>\w+)/$'` but this doesn't return anything either. I'm lost. Could someone help?

Eg. string: `localhost:8080/details/1234/`

Comment: Can you provide an example that contains "details/1234" that you are using against your regex.

Comment: Updated question with example string

Comment: That pattern is correct and works fine for the URL 'localhost:8080/details/1234/'

Comment: Your regex has end and beginning of line anchors.  Your example does not have a `/` at the end.  So there is no way for your regex to match your example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Added a screenshot from Pythex. Doesn't seem to be working :(

@RonRosenfeld What would you suggest I change? I removed the second trailing slash and tried `localhost:8080/details/1234` and also, tried `localhost:8080/details/1234/` with the given regex. Pythex didn't find a match in either case

Comment: I don't understand what Pythex has to do with anything. This is Django, and Django matches against the path: "/details/1234/". That works absolutely fine with the pattern you have.

Comment: I was just using Pythex to validate the RegEx. You're right - the issue itself resides in my Django code. I have posted a Django version of the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32916267/1409180

Could you see if you could help?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use urlparse to help you out more?

```
from urlparse import urlparse

d = urlparse('http://localhost:8080/details/1234')
```

output:

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='localhost:8080', path='/details/1234', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Getting path:

```
>>> d.path
'/details/1234'
>>>
```

If you want to use your regex after you extract the path, you can then use your regex with a small modification:

I've added `/?` which will look for '/' or no '/'.

`^/?details/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)$`

pythex extracted that as:

`article_id 1234`

Comment: I've added a screenshot from Pythex - could you tell me if I'm doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Yes. Get rid of the '^'. The '^' means to start from the beginning of the string. I removed that from your regex and it worked.

Comment: If you use urlparse and then apply your regex it will work. Actually, a small modification to your regex will help you too. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This certainly seems to be working on Pythex. Not on Django though - I have posted a Django version of the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32916267/1409180

If you are good with Django, could you see if you could help me there?

Answer (score 0):

try this;

> /details\/(?P[0-9]+)/$/

I removed the `^` symbol at the beginning. Because that symbol (called *carat*) tries to search the pattern ["from the start of the line"](https://qualysguard.qualys.com/qwebhelp/fo_help/module_pc/policies/regular_expression_symbols.htm), and your pattern `details/...` doesn't start at the start of the line !

I also removed the `r` ([Python’s raw string notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)) and then I escaped the `/` character to be consistent :)
[image: Pyhex scr]

Comment: This certainly seems to be working on Pythex. Not on Django though - I have posted a Django version of the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32916267/1409180

If you are good with Django, could you see if you could help me there?

Comment: Mmm, I'm not good at Django but I'm looking your question :)
Did you removed the '^'?, seems that can be the cause of the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Here you try to pass a "Django-style" url with a carat `^` at the beginning. Django knows that all your urls in urls.py are **relative** and should start with 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8080 or whatever you set when started a runserver or in your `settings.py`. Pythex do not know this, so it tries to find any matches where **absolute** path starts with "/details/..." and, of course, fails. Hence, removing a carat from the beginning of your regex should do the trick.

However, as Daniel Roseman already mentioned, that should work fine in django.